# Laravel 5 - query using a model, get results with a different model

Tags: php, laravel-5

### Question

Is it possible to return model query results via different model than the one that originally made the query?

For example, if we have two models, `ModelA` and `ModelB`, and we fetch some database results:

```
$modelA = new ModelA;

$results = $modelA->all();

dd($results);
```

Instead of a collection of ModelA objects, can it somehow return ModelB objects? The desired output, for example:

```
Collection {#325 ▼
    #modelA_Table: Array:4 [▼
        0 => ModelB { #297 ▶}
        1 => ModelB { #306 ▶}
        2 => ModelB { #311 ▶}
        3 => ModelB { #318 ▶}
    ]
}
```

### Context

Relationship is a taxonomy hierarchy, where `ModelB` is a sub-taxon of `ModelA`:

```
class ModelA extends Model {
    protected $table = 'ModelA_Table';

    protected $fillable = [];

    private $discriminator = 'a_type';

    public function __construct(array $attributes = array()){
        $this->initialize();
        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }

    private function initialize() {
        $this->fillable = array_merge($this->fillable, $this->fillables());
    }

    private function fillables() {
        return [
            'a_name',
            'a_type'
            'a_price'
        ];
    }

}

class ModelB extends ModelA {

    protected $fillable = [];

    public function __construct(array $attributes = array()){
        $this->initialize();
        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }

    private function initialize() {
        $this->fillable = array_merge($this->fillable, $this->fillables());
    }

    private function fillables() {
        return [
            'b_width',
            'b_height'
        ];

    }
}
```

Both models are different taxons (classification levels) of a single entity persisted by single-table-inheritance (ModelA_Table).

Analogy -- General : Specific  ::  ModelA : ModelB  ::  Vehicle : Truck

Back to the code, when ModelB is instantiated, it will append its own fillables to its inherited parent-fillables, via initialize() in the constructor. Where ModelB can inherit ModelA's fillable, the reverse is not true; ModelA cannot inherit ModelB's fillables.  I can ask for Truck->find(1) and get both Truck and Vehicle attributes, but Vehicle->find(1) will only give me Vehicle attributes because Vehicle (the general taxonomy) cannot inherit from its child (from the specific taxonomy).

That leaves me at where I am now.

---

Basically, if ModelA is Vehicle, and ModelB is Car, I need this to happen:

1) Vehicle model fetches row by id

2) Vehicle model looks at field 'a_type'

3) 'a_type' will be either 'Car', 'Motorcycle', or 'Truck', etc

4) The returned hydrated objects will be of the 'a_type' class

---

Query using ModelA, get results using ModelB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using [Jeff Madsen's solution](http://codebyjeff.com/blog/2014/07/single-table-inheritence-in-laravel) of modifying the Eloquent Model's `newFromBuilder` method.

Model.php:

```
public function newFromBuilder($attributes = array())
{
    $instance = $this->newInstance(array(), true);

    $instance->setRawAttributes((array) $attributes, true);

    return $instance;
}
```

override in extending class with:

```
public function newFromBuilder($attributes = array())
{
    $class = $this->{$this->discriminator} . ucwords($attributes->status);
    $instance = new $class;
    $instance->exists = true;
    $instance->setRawAttributes((array) $attributes, true);
    return $instance;
}
```

The new class will be `$class`, which is the value of the retrieved discriminator field, which is designated by the property `discriminator`